# C: GDB: Terminal shows line by line search for built in functions

Tags: c, gdb

I haven't found anyone with a similar problem.

My problem is, whenever I run gdb in the last 2 weeks, it searches for all functions like fopen, printf, calloc, etc... This is quit annoying as sometimes i have to step through over 100 lines or set another break point. It all just takes a lot more time and this didn't used to happen.

Anybody have any ideas?

```
18      char *temp =  strtok(ara, " ");
(gdb) s
strtok () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S:88
88  ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) s
91  in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
?? () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S:80 from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
80  in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
?? () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S:81 from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
81  in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
strtok () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S:92
92  in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
100 in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
101 in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
103 in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) 
104 in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
105 in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
106 in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
107 in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
111 in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
113 in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
122 in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
127 in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
128 in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
129 in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
130 in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
146 in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
153 in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
154 in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb) s
155 in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/strtok.S
(gdb)
```

Comment: Use `n` instead of `s` in gdb to step through.

Comment: Don't remember ever using n but that works!

Answer (score 0):

Adding comment as answer.

Use `n` instead of `s` in gdb to step through.